# How to change numbers of lines (of grid) for x axis?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a big problem, and I do not know how to solve it ..

My chart in Highcharts is "Scatter 3d"

If I don't misunderstood, the number of grid lines on the x-axis depends on the width of the chart.
So most will be large (really long, and depends on the values of "margin") and the greater the number of grid lines for the x-axis (I am referring to the lines for "back" and "bottom" frames).

But this is my problem, so i ask you if is possible to set the number of lines in another way?

See this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5846xjkr/

```
xAxis: {
        min: 175,
        max: 180,
        gridLineWidth: 1
    },
```

In this chart there are 4 lines.
But the first line (and so the first band) it is not equal to other lines and bands.

but especially the problem is that under the first line there isn't a value! 
And this is for me very important.

While if there is a way to change the number of lines (i can't change values of margin), in this case i wanted 3 lines where:

First line: value 175

Second line: value 177.5

Third line: value 180

Three equal lines, with 3 values. 
I tried with "tickpositioner" but doesn't work..

I hope that you can help me...

**EDIT**

with a comment posted by Pawel is ok, but now i have a problem with "formatter tooltip", i used tooltip in this way:

```
   formatter: function() {
                 if(this.point.x < 10.1) {
                return   code code;
            }
       return false
    }
```

that 10.1 because max of x axis was 10. But if the max of axis change, so how i can to do?

Thanks

Comment: TickPositioner works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/5846xjkr/1/

Comment: Thanks Pawel you are great, really! but now i have a problem with "max value" and tooltip formatter, see edit please

Comment: Well, you have access to `this.point.series.xAxis.max` instead of hardcoded value. However, when x/y for the point is outside the extremes, then point shouldn't be visible, I guess?

Comment: thanks Pawel, but values of x axis (and so of new lines) has z index more higher than tooltip and this is a problem. Is possible to set z index of value? Maybe is beacause in "Labels" i added "useHTML:true"....

Comment: Yes, that's the case - when you set `useHTML: true`, then labels are rendered in HTML, instead of SVG. You can't have part of SVG above, and part below of some HTML tags.

Comment: but also "tooltip" has "useHTML: true"...

Comment: Yes, that refers to the formatter, which generates content. Background+borders+shadows are still generated in SVG. Disable that option and in formatter generate that styles and should work. Of course don't forget to set higher z-index for the tooltip.

Comment: @PawełFus   "this.point.series.xAxis.max" is the only way to have max of xAxis ?  I must to draw line on bottom frame, the line start in the min of xAxis and end in the max of xAxis. I can't to put the values of min and max to data  to draw line, because min and max of axis changed (rember thread where i changed width and depth of chart?). I want to put min and max of xAxis to data to draw line, but  this.point.series.xAxis.max doesn't work. Why ? http://jsfiddle.net/L5hfpvdr/ see the code at line 95..

Comment: Your demo doesn't work. And whatever you are trying to achieve in line #95 - it won't work. I won't learn you how JavaScript works, but in short use `this` only when you know what you are doing. And in your case I would limit usage to functions only (e.g. formatter). Anyway, have you tried to use `addPlotLine` method instead? In `chart.events.load` callback.

Comment: How whatever i am trying to achieve in line #95 - it won't work ? i tried also with  chart.xAxis[0].min; and chart.xAxis[0].max but doesn't work :(

Comment: In previous example `this` was a reference to the `window`. You can't use `chart` because it's `undefined` at this moment. As I said, use `load` callback, where you have `this` which is reference to the chart itself. Welcome in JS! ;)

Comment: I'am trying with load callback but doesn't work :( is too difficult for me... I had asked for help for other topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989321/debugging-code-about-lines-and-points-in-highcharts?noredirect=1#comment46228536_28989321

Comment: How is that question connected to the second one? Here you have problem with using `this` and `chart`. There you ask for suggestions to improve: `as you can see it would be too code, and it would not be a great idea`.