# Debugging code about lines and points in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i'm thinking how to debug the code, for my scatter 3d chart, about lines and points.

This is the code:

```
 series: [{
        name: 'Reading',
        colorByPoint: true,                     
        data: coloriamo()},{ // this function draws some points
        data: [[0,750,0],[10,750,0] //this data draw a line
        ],
        lineWidth: 1,
        enableMouseTracking: false,
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.51)'
        },{  
       data: [[175,750,5],[180,750,5] //draw line in the half of bottom frame
        ],
        lineWidth: 1,
        enableMouseTracking: false,
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.51)'
        },{  
        data: [[0,750,10],[10,750,10] //draw a line
        ],
        lineWidth: 1,
        enableMouseTracking: false,
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.51)'
        },{  
            data: [[11,750,-0.3]],  //draw a point for first line               
             dataLabels: {
               style: {
                    textShadow: 0
                },
                enabled: true,
                crop: false,
                overflow: false,
                 format: 0+'\u00B0'+' N',
            }, 
            marker: {
                enabled: false,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            }                   
    },{  
            data: [[11,750,4.7]],    //a point for second line              
             dataLabels: {
                style: {
                    textShadow: 0
                },
                enabled: true,
                crop: false,
                overflow: false,
                 format: 5+'\u00B0'+' N',
            }, 
            marker: {
                enabled: false,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            }                   
    },{  
            data: [[11,750,9.3]], //draw line for third line                
             dataLabels: {
               style: {
                    textShadow: 0
                },
                enabled: true,
                crop: false,
                overflow: false,
                 format: 10+'\u00B0'+' N',
            }, 
            marker: {
                enabled: false,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            }                   
    }]
```

this is jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/h2qxn54b/

the problem is that "**max:**" and "**min:**" of xAxis and Zaxis changed, so also values of DATA (for draw lines and point) will change.

I must to add a function in data that return array to draw lines and points, but i don't know where is the better way to do.

The worst way is to make 3 functions (one function for each "data line") and 3 functions for points, and to add each function to **data**.

```
 var mycharts = [[35,40,173,180]]; //min.zAxis,max.zAxis,min.xAxis,maxxAxis

 function linefirst(){
      for (var s = 0; s <mycharts.length; s++) {
      var cas= mycharts[s];
      var minZ= cas[0];
      var maxZ= cas[1];
      var minX= cas[2];
      var maxX= cas[3];
      var middleZ= (minZ+maxZ)/2;
      } 
     var arraylinef=[];
     arraylinef.push([[minX,750,minZ],[maxX,750,minZ]]);
     return arraylinef;
     }



 function linesecond(){
      for (var s = 0; s <mycharts.length; s++) {
      var cas= mycharts[s];
      var minZ= cas[0];
      var maxZ= cas[1];
      var minX= cas[2];
      var maxX= cas[3];
      var middleZ= (minZ+maxZ)/2;
      } 
     var arraylines=[];
     arraylines.push([[minX,750,middleZ],[maxX,750,middleZ]]);
     return arraylines;
     }



 function linethird(){
      for (var s = 0; s <mycharts.length; s++) {
      var cas= mycharts[s];
      var minZ= cas[0];
      var maxZ= cas[1];
      var minX= cas[2];
      var maxX= cas[3];
      var middleZ= (minZ+maxZ)/2;
      } 
     var arraylinet=[];
     arraylinet.push([[minX,750,maxZ],[maxX,750,maxZ]]);
     return arraylinet;
     }
```

And now 3 functions to draw 3 points:

```
 function pointfirst(){
      for (var s = 0; s <mycharts.length; s++) {
      var cas= mycharts[s];
      var minZ= cas[0];
      var maxZ= cas[1];
      var minX= cas[2];
      var maxX= cas[3];
      var pointX= maxX+1;
      var pointfZ= minZ-0.3;
      var middleZ= (minZ+maxZ)/2;
      } 
     var arraypointf=[];
     arraypointf.push([[pointX,750,pointfZ]]);
     return arraypointf;
     }



 function pointsecond(){
      for (var s = 0; s <mycharts.length; s++) {
      var cas= mycharts[s];
      var minZ= cas[0];
      var maxZ= cas[1];
      var minX= cas[2];
      var maxX= cas[3];
      var pointX= maxX+1;
      var middleZ= (minZ+maxZ)/2;
      var pointsZ= middleZ-0.3;         
      } 
     var arraypoints=[];
     arraypoints.push([[pointX,750,pointsZ]]);
     return arraypoints;
     }



 function pointthird(){
      for (var s = 0; s <mycharts.length; s++) {
      var cas= mycharts[s];
      var minZ= cas[0];
      var maxZ= cas[1];
      var minX= cas[2];
      var maxX= cas[3];
      var pointX= maxX+1;         
      var pointtZ= maxZ-0.5;         
      } 
     var arraypointt=[];
     arraypointt.push([[pointX,750,pointtZ]]);
     return arraypointt;
     }
```

as you can see it would be too code, and it would not be a great idea...
So can you suggest me ?

Sorry for the big post and the big code...

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. `min` and `max` changes? When? How? And when they change the points also have to change? Why? What changes?

Comment: You are right Ondloss, I explained badly, and I did not want to make the post even longer and with other code. So, see the array "mychart".. That array changed, beacause i make that array with another function that there isn't in the code that i have posted or in the jdfiddle linked. In my code, before the chart is rendered, is possible to choose a chart with different width and depth. When you choose the chart, to create "mychart". When change the chart also min and max of axis changed. If you see the code of functions for draw lines and points, you can see that data is important.

Comment: Values of data are important to draw lines and point.. I believe that the code i have thinked is bad and not intelligent. Now do you understood more? Sorry :)